# Find which process is causing utilization on specific hard disk

Tags: monitoring, hard-drive, ubuntu-14.04

Our server has multiple hard disks and runs many processes. We have high disk utilization on one of our disks and I want to find out which process(es) causing this. I used *iotop* command but it doesn't filter by disks and it has a large output. I used *nmon* and it only says we have a lot of read io on my disk. How can I filter processes by hard disk and sort by io usage?

OS: ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your kernel was configured with CONFIG_FTRACE, which is usually the case, you can get detailed information using [iosnoop](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/iosnoop), one of the scripts from the Brendan Gregg trace and performance collection. Eg:

```
$ sudo /opt/perf-tools-master/bin/iosnoop 5
Tracing block I/O for 5 seconds (buffered)...
COMM         PID    TYPE DEV      BLOCK        BYTES     LATms
jbd2/sda1-33 335    WS   8,0      10551960     4096       1.67
jbd2/sda1-33 335    WS   8,0      15472840     4096       1.72
gawk         6368   WS   8,0      10393480     4096       0.35
kworker/0:1H 295    WS   8,0      129522736    20480      1.97
xterm        1864   FWS  8,0      18446744073709551615 0          0.02
jbd2/sda1-33 335    WS   8,0      10393488     8192       1.73
jbd2/sda1-33 335    FWS  8,0      18446744073709551615 0          0.13
/usr/bin/mon 746    WS   8,0      10393504     4096       0.34
Xorg         1514   FWS  8,0      18446744073709551615 0          0.06
/usr/bin/mon 746    R    8,0      19868992     4096       0.22
```

Comment: Thanks! I can filter devices with "-d" option. But commands shows as "<...>". Why is that? Do commands have large text which it doesn't show? How can I see them?

Comment: iosnoop tries to find the process causing the i/o from the stack. Perhaps `<...>` means it failed in this. See the [blog article](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-07-16/iosnoop-for-linux.html) for some info, and try the `-Q` option too.